The ODE can be solved for a general form, but fail for a particular form
As the title, I try to solve an ODE:
$$
   y^{\prime}=(x-1)(x-3)y+F(\frac{xy^2-4xy+3x-y^2+4y-1}{x-3})
$$
And it seems that the ODE can be solved using Lie Symmetry method in Maple. But as I choose f to be a simple exponential function,dsolve fails to give the solution. I also try the DEtools:-symgen to get the symmetry, but fail for the particular case as well.
Can anyone tell me what's the problem? Is there some internal bug in Maple?
ODE := y(x) = (x - 1)*(x - 3)*diff(y(x), x) + f((x*y(x)^2 - 4*x*y(x) + 3*x - y(x)^2 + 4*y(x) - 1)/(x - 3))
dsolve(ODE, implicit) #Succeed in general form
DEtools:-symgen(ODE)
ODE1 := y(x) = (x - 1)*(x - 3)*diff(y(x), x) + exp((x*y(x)^2 - 4*x*y(x) + 3*x - y(x)^2 + 4*y(x) - 1)/(x - 3))
dsolve(ODE1,implicit) #Fail for choosing f = exp
DEtools:-symgen(ODE1)


Are you asking why the internals of Maple’s ODE solver behave differently in different cases?

Yes exactly. Because the result should be same.

Your best bet will be to send an email to Maple support.

@Steven_Huang The ODE in your question is not the same as in your Maple code.
